# issue with updating NordPass, an error with snap

Tags: update-manager, gimp

I'm trying to utilise a password manager for simplicity.

NordPass isn't working and isn't updating, the photo below.

The NordPass application doesn't move from the login page for some reason.

*A screenshot would just show a the application page with my email and not moving to the password page. I would upload that but I haven't got an image manipulator, I'm trying to install GIMP but this is also proving troublesome.*

For now, I'm keen to get a password manager working, does this not work for anyone else?

I have contacted Nord and I'm awaiting their email, been 4/5 days now.

Any advice would be most helpful.

NordPass version 4.33.11

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try

```
pkill -f nordpass
```

Then check for updates.